How do you calculate the angular velocity vector only having access to the spin rate and the spin axis of a golf ball?
I have limited knowledge of physics concepts so I thought I reach out to see if anyone can help me.
I am trying to simulate a ball trajectory in 3d space. I am using the equations for flight from this paper (https://www.math.union.edu/~wangj/courses/previous/math238w13/Golf%20Ball%20Flight%20Dynamics2.pdf).
The information I have access to is the spin rate and spin axis of the ball. I also have access to the elevation angle and the azimuth angle of the ball trajectory with the ball speed. How do I caculate the angular velocity vector based on this information?

If you know the spin axis, isn’t the angular velocity just that vector times the spin rate?

Spin rate (scalar $\dot{\theta}$) and spin axis (unit vector $\hat{u}$) combine to give the rotational velocity vector
$$ \vec{\omega} = \dot{\theta}\; \hat{u}$$

The angular velocity vector has a magnitude equal to its spin rate and in the direction parallel to the spin axis as given by the right-hand rule. To understand the right-hand rule, stick out your right thumb and curl the rest of your fingers on your right hand. When you align the curl of your fingers with the spin of the ball, your thumb points in the direction of the angular velocity vector.

Adapted from Wikipedia
For example, let's say a golf ball is hover directly in front of you and spinning counter-clockwise. If you holding your right hand in front of your face with your palm facing to the left, you will see that your fingers will curl in the direction of the ball and your thumb is pointed back at you. We can define a coordinate system like this: $+x$ is to the left, $+y$ is up, and $+z$ is directly away. This would mean your thumb and the angular velocity point in the $-z$ direction. So, the angular velocity vector would be $\vec\omega = [0, 0, -\omega]$ where $\omega$ is the spin rate.
For another example with the same coordinate system, let's say the golf ball is headed away from you (along $+z$) with top spin. In this case, hold out your right hand with your palm down and thumb sticking out. Curling your fingers mimics the spin of the ball, so your thumb that sticks out to the left ($+x$) is the direction of the angular velocity. In vector form, this is $\vec\omega = [\omega, 0, 0]$.

This helps a lot, thank you :)

Here is a C++ code. You can easily use glm::vec3 instead of custom_math::vector_3.
custom_math::vector_3 acceleration(custom_math::vector_3 pos, custom_math::vector_3 vel, custom_math::vector_3 ang_vel)
{
    // http://twu.tennis-warehouse.com/learning_center/aerodynamics2.php
    const double air_density = 1.225;
    const double lift_coeff = 0.05;
    const double drag_coeff = 0.55;
    const double ball_cross_section = 0.0034;
    const double ball_mass = 0.0585;

    // Gravitation, in metres per second, per second
    custom_math::vector_3 grav_accel(0, -9.81, 0);

    // Magnus effect, in metres per second, per second
    // http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/329/lectures/node43.html
    // http://spiff.rit.edu/richmond/baseball/traj/traj.html
    custom_math::vector_3 magnus_accel = vel.cross(ang_vel)*0.5*air_density*lift_coeff*ball_cross_section / ball_mass;

    // Wind and drag, in metres per second, per second
    custom_math::vector_3 wind_vel(2.77778, 0, 0); // in metres per second
    custom_math::vector_3 drag_vel = wind_vel - vel;
    custom_math::vector_3 drag_accel = drag_vel*drag_vel.length()*0.5*air_density*drag_coeff*ball_cross_section / ball_mass;
    
    return grav_accel + magnus_accel + drag_accel;
}


Thank you very much! I appreciate your help
